# Picard SamToFastq only extracts one read, then throws an error

Tags: bioinformatics, dna-sequence, fastq, picard, bam

I'm trying to extract some FastQ files from bam files. Picard can do this with SamToFastq as it says in the documentation for this tool it accepts either a bam or sam file.

But when I run it, it only extracts one read, and then exits. Here is the error message. Any help is appreciated.

```
[davy@xxxx picard-tools-1.70]$ java -jar SamToFastq.jar I=/home/davy/xxx_trio_data/xxxx-1.bam F=/home/davy/xxx_trio_data/1005-1.fastq
[Wed Jun 20 14:14:21 BST 2012] net.sf.picard.sam.SamToFastq INPUT=/home/davy/xxx_trio_data/xxxx-1.bam FASTQ=/home/davy/xxxx_trio_data/xxxx-1.fastq    OUTPUT_PER_RG=false RE_REVERSE=true INCLUDE_NON_PF_READS=false READ1_TRIM=0 READ2_TRIM=0 INCLUDE_NON_PRIMARY_ALIGNMENTS=false VERBOSITY=INFO QUIET=false VALIDATION_STRINGENCY=STRICT COMPRESSION_LEVEL=5 MAX_RECORDS_IN_RAM=500000 CREATE_INDEX=false CREATE_MD5_FILE=false
[Wed Jun 20 14:14:21 BST 2012] Executing as davy@xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xx.xx on Linux 2.6.34.9-69.fc13.x86_64 amd64; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_18-b18; Picard version: 1.70(1215)
[Wed Jun 20 14:14:21 BST 2012] net.sf.picard.sam.SamToFastq done. Elapsed time: 0.00 minutes.
Runtime.totalMemory()=2029715456
FAQ:  http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/picard/index.php?title=Main_Page
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:571)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:349)
        at net.sf.picard.sam.SamToFastq.doWork(SamToFastq.java:156)
        at net.sf.picard.cmdline.CommandLineProgram.instanceMain(CommandLineProgram.java:177)
        at net.sf.picard.sam.SamToFastq.main(SamToFastq.java:118)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the data is paired end, not single read as I had initially thought, and picard require a second outfile in this instance specified with the SECOND_END_FASTQ option.